AG Grid - agSetColumnFilter needs dynamic API search integration
I am currently using AG Grid with React, and I am new to AG Grid implementation. I have searched through Google and Chat, but the suggestions I found did not help me. Furthermore, I need suggestions on how to trigger an API call every time the filter text changes instead of filtering the users locally. The getUsers method below currently makes an API call and gets a list of 20 users added to the filter. However, my new requirement is to make new API calls with filter text when the filter text changes and display the results in the filter.
Below My columnDef Code
{
    headerName: 'users',
    field: 'users',
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    minWidth: 80,
    filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
    filterParams: {
      values: getUsers
    },
    cellRenderer: (....)
  }

